# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI - PageNotFound noHandlerFound

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I had little experience in spring and wanted to develop an application in spring.
Getting the following error :

```
Oct 23, 2015 1:13:37 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/<app>/admin/device/admin/device/getClosestReviewers] in DispatcherServlet with name 'app'
```

invoking the url this way,
http://localhost:8080/app/admin/device/getClosestReviewers?deviceId=5b0d9a27-b0f8-43c9-8a4f-59cc1ba63653&radius=6

what i am missing, i tried a couple of ways but nothing seem to be working

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/getClosestReviewers", produces = "application/json")
public JSONResponse getClosestReviewers(@RequestParam("deviceId") String deviceId,@RequestParam("radius") int radius) {
    JSONResponse response = new JSONResponse();


    return response;
}
```

Comment: Add your web.xml and spring context file to your post, then it will give clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think the value you are providing for RequestMapping is not correct. Do you have any RequestMapping at the class level?

Comment: yeah, i had the following mapping @Controller
@RequestMapping("admin/device")
public class DeviceServiceImpl implements DeviceService . And also, not sure why "admin/device" is referred twice in resolving the url No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/app/admin/device/admin/device/getClosestReviewers]

Comment: Can you provide your web.xml or equivalent java config ?

Comment: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>app</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Do other controllers behave similarly ? Is /admin/device getting prepended to all the mappings ?

Comment: it is appended to all the mappings